# Nuxt.js - Implementing a component using Plugin

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js

I would like to implement a custom Toaster component into my NuxtJs application by this method `this.$toast.show({})` What is the best way of approaching this? Sadly I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I arrive one year late...
I had the same proplem. Here is my code:

The index of my plugin (index.js ; Nofification.vue is a classical Vue component):

```js
import Notifications from './Notifications.vue'

const NotificationStore = {
  state: [], // here the notifications will be added
  settings: {
    overlap: false,
    horizontalAlign: 'center',
    type: 'info',
    timeout: 5000,
    ...
  },
  setOptions(options) {
    this.settings = Object.assign(this.settings, options)
  },
  removeNotification(timestamp) {
    ...
  },
  addNotification(notification) {
    ...
  },
  notify(notification) {
    ...
  },
}

const NotificationsPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    const app = new Vue({
      data: {
        notificationStore: NotificationStore,
      },
      methods: {
        notify(notification) {
          this.notificationStore.notify(notification)
        },
      },
    })
    Vue.prototype.$notify = app.notify
    Vue.notify = app.notify
    Vue.prototype.$notifications = app.notificationStore
    Vue.component('Notifications', Notifications)
    if (options) {
      NotificationStore.setOptions(options)
    }
  },
}

export default NotificationsPlugin
```

Here I call my plugin and inject it in Nuxt:

```js
import Notifications from '~/components/NotificationPlugin'
Vue.use(Notifications)
export default (context, inject) => {
  inject('notify', Vue.notify)
}
```

In my case, I use it in another plugin (nuxtjs axios).

```js
import NOTIFICATIONS from '~/constants/notifications'

export default function ({ error, $axios, app }) {
  // Using few axios helpers (https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers):

  $axios.onError((axiosError) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('Axios: An error occured! ', axiosError, axiosError.response)
    if (process.server) {
      ...
    } else {
      app.$notify({
        message: 'Mon message',
        timeout: NOTIFICATIONS.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        icon: 'tim-icons icon-spaceship',
        horizontalAlign: NOTIFICATIONS.DEFAULT_ALIGN_HORIZONTAL,
        verticalAlign: NOTIFICATIONS.DEFAULT_ALIGN_VERTICAL,
        type: 'success',
      })
      console.log('PRINT ERROR')
      return Promise.resolve(true)
    }
  })
}
```

As I injected it, I think I could have done `export default function ({ error, $axios, app, $notify }) {` and directly use $notify (and not the app.$notify).

If you want a better understanding, feel free to consult @nuxtjs/toast which works the same way:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/community-modules/blob/master/packages/toast/plugin.js

And the matching Vue component:
https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted/blob/master/src/index.js

Good luck, this is not easy stuff. I'll try to add something easier to understand in the docs!

Answer (score 0):

you can find in this package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toasted`

installation

`npm install vue-toasted --save`

make a file as name `toast.js` in plugin folder

toast.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';

Vue.use(Toasted)
```

add this plugin to nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/toast', ssr: false },
  ],
```

now you able to use in your methods like this

```
this.$toasted.show('hello i am your toast')
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks sid, however, I would like to make my own custom plugin, and need to know the best way of doing it.

Comment: than you need to make your own dependency and implement in nuxt

Comment: This is what I am asking. How do I create my own component and implement it into another component via `this.$foo`

Comment: ohh i see this is call dependancy injection in vue learn about mixins or https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/dependency-injection-in-vue-applications/ this link gives you example

Comment: This shows you how to inject services etc, not components like the vue-toasted plugin you posted above